# Can we make HTTPS connection without SSL certificate?

Tags: networking, https, ssl-certificate

I've some discussion with my colleague whether we can make HTTPS connection without using SSL certificate. I'm quite confused about this. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Somewhat related to: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate - In fact the second answer is exactly right for you. It's "no" and that answer explains why.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I'm wondering about the possibility of making that kind of connection atleast in theory although in practical environment it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do HTTPS connections without SSL. The way it works is complicated and as mentioned in the comments there is a great answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate).

But to summarize the reason why it's *not possible*:

HTTPS *needs* an SSL certificate, you can think of SSL as the `S` in `HTTPS`, since the secure connection is made using the certificate. A client sends a request to a server, they do a secure handshake (which requires the certificate in order to create and verify the keys) and then proceed to business as usual.

Any browser will throw a million red flaws if you try to circumvent this behavior. You could trick your own server to believe data is coming as HTTPS rather than HTTP in some cases (if you have control over it), but you won't be able to fool browsers.

Comment: Thank you. It means even in theory we cannot create HTTPS connection without SSL certificate. Thank you again.

Comment: I recommend reading the answer I linked above. It's a good read. 

Please accept the answer as correct if it is so. Thanks!

Comment: Until this answer I have thought it was a vendor lock in, but can we be sure https is safe?

Comment: @DanFroberg why would HTTPS be a vendor lock-in? It's a standard, not vendor-related. The SSL certificate can be provided by many vendors and you can switch between them.

whether it's safe depends on what you mean by it. It does its job correctly (encrypting traffic) and it's safe in that case.

Comment: @Obed Parlapiano. I don't remember why I thought it was not a vendor lock in, but now you say vendor is needed. The risk of an outdated certificate makes it less safe. Vendor can block because of a missed payment or a fact checking. That is a vendor lock in. The time to switch between vendors to find a reliable takes time.

Comment: @DanFroberg nowadays everyone uses LetsEncrypt, which creates the certificates for free and automatically